# Click Once fails with strange 404 , unknown subtype

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, clickonce

Tried to get Click once running (Wpf app, .NET4, IIS 7.5). After solving the first dozen problems I now seem to be stuck. 
Clickonce fails with a 404, stating an "unknown subtype" error. I've already added all required filetypes to the IIS mimetypes, so that is not the problem (.application, .manifest,.deploy, .msp, .msu). Even more so, as I created the manifest with the "use .deploy" option, so all files actually have the .deploy extension.

The strange thing is, that the error message states:
Couldnt' download "http://myserver/1.0.0.0/mysubdir/my.diverse.namespaces.xyz"

Entering the url "http://myserver/1.0.0.0/mysubdir/my.diverse.namespaces.xyz" into IE yields indeed a 404, but adding a ".deploy" at the end of the URL downloads the file nicely.
I checked the manifest file and it lists all files WITH the .deploy extension.
It just makes no sense. Why does the application try to access using the wrong filenames? Or is this a different problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: after creating the manifest again, the files listed in the manifest DON'T have the ".deploy" extension. The download now fails on a .xml file

Comment: The error occurs with a xyz.noreferenceassembly File in the Codecontracts subfolder. This could be pure coincidence though, as this is the first file in the application manifest.

Comment: Deleted the whole Codecontracts stuff. Now it fails on a fairly normal xml file.

Comment: It seems like ClickOnce can really be a black box of obscure features. I recently stumbled onto this project which reads ClickOnce files, mimics ClickOnce behaviour, but tries to make sure it works: https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/NSync . I must admit I haven't used it, but I just thought to drop it here, as you were desperate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define MIME types. You missed XAML.

Of course adding a .deploy to the URL works -- the files should all end in .deploy except (IIRC) the two manifests (yourapp.exe.manifest and yourapp.application). we had this problem once, where it would stop on a specific file for no reason that we could discern. I don't remember exactly what the problem was; I'll check my notes and report back. In the meantime, do you have a proxy server? Are there proxy settings in IE?